# Is it problematic to have packet loss on a specific node but not on subsequent nodes in the route?

Tags: networking, traceroute, mtr

Here is the result of two `mtr` reports on ipv4 and ipv6 to google.com

[image]

I had very consistent lag spikes when ipv6 was enabled. I disabled ipv6 and all my lag spikes disappeared. I concluded the problem was the node that had 80% loss on the ipv6 report.

I showed this graph to a very experienced network engineer, and he told me that this did not indicate a problem. He said it was likely but not certain that the node with 80% loss was a result of the router dropping the ping when the TTL was 0 because the offloading of the packet from the optimized network ASIC to the CPU was full.

Is it true that this report does not indicate a problem.

(sorry for the screen shot, I no longer have it in text form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like ping and traceroute, mtr relies on intermediate hops returning an ICMP *time exceeded* for the probe packets.

ICMP processing is very low priority though and commonly limited in frequency. That means that you can *not* reliably deduce there's general packet loss on a certain hop when you see ICMP message loss indicated. In contrast, if subsequent hops show no packet loss at all, it's ICMP handling or rate limiting you see, *not* actual packet loss.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what he said.

Answer (score 2):

It is a rate limiting on those nodes.

If the packet loss was caused by congestion all next hops until destination would observe some packet loss.

Just try to use: `mtr -i 20 www.google.com`